# WordPress Media library not showing old images in Gridview, list view shows images

Tags: wordpress

I have create one script to insert custom field image for all categories and database entry is fine.

Now, when I go to Media library it only loads my latest images, old images are not showing. Spinner continue rotation and Ajax call goes infinite.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons to fail older image loads. Please turn on Debug Mode and check Debug Log and share the information here so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

add_action( 'business_add_form_fields', 'add_category_image', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'created_business', 'save_category_image', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'business_edit_form_fields','update_category_image', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'edited_business','updated_category_image', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts',  'load_media');
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'add_script');

function load_media() {
    if( ! isset( $_GET['taxonomy'] ) || $_GET['taxonomy'] != 'business' ) {
      return;
    }
    wp_enqueue_media();
}
function add_category_image( $taxonomy ) { ?>
    <div class="form-field term-group">
        <label for="showcase-taxonomy-extra-detail-id"><?php _e( 'Business Extra Details', 'launchpm' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" id="showcase-taxonomy-extra-detail-id" name="showcase-taxonomy-extra-detail-id" class="" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-field term-group">
      <label for="showcase-taxonomy-image-id"><?php _e( 'Image', 'launchpm' ); ?></label>
      <input type="hidden" id="showcase-taxonomy-image-id" name="showcase-taxonomy-image-id" class="custom_media_url" value="">
      <div id="category-image-wrapper"></div>
      <p>
        <input type="button" class="button button-secondary showcase_tax_media_button" id="showcase_tax_media_button" name="showcase_tax_media_button" value="<?php _e( 'Add Image', 'launchpm' ); ?>" />
        <input type="button" class="button button-secondary showcase_tax_media_remove" id="showcase_tax_media_remove" name="showcase_tax_media_remove" value="<?php _e( 'Remove Image', 'launchpm' ); ?>" />
      </p>
    </div>
  <?php }
  /**
 * Edit the form field
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function update_category_image( $term, $taxonomy ) { ?>
    <tr class="form-field term-group-wrap">
        <th scope="row">
            <label for="showcase-taxonomy-extra-detail-id"><?php _e( 'Business Extra Details', 'launchpm' ); ?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <?php $extra_detail = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'showcase-taxonomy-extra-detail-id', true ); ?>
            <input type="text" id="showcase-taxonomy-extra-detail-id" name="showcase-taxonomy-extra-detail-id" value="<?php echo  $extra_detail ; ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field term-group-wrap">
        <th scope="row">
        <label for="showcase-taxonomy-image-id"><?php _e( 'Image', 'launchpm' ); ?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
        <?php $image_id = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'showcase-taxonomy-image-id', true ); ?>
        <input type="hidden" id="showcase-taxonomy-image-id" name="showcase-taxonomy-image-id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $image_id ); ?>">
        <div id="category-image-wrapper">
            <?php if( $image_id ) { ?>
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="button" class="button button-secondary showcase_tax_media_button" id="showcase_tax_media_button" name="showcase_tax_media_button" value="<?php _e( 'Add Image', 'showcase' ); ?>" />
            <input type="button" class="button button-secondary showcase_tax_media_remove" id="showcase_tax_media_remove" name="showcase_tax_media_remove" value="<?php _e( 'Remove Image', 'showcase' ); ?>" />
        </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php }
  /**
    * Save the form field
    * @since 1.0.0
    */
    function save_category_image( $term_id, $tt_id ) {
        if( isset( $_POST['showcase-taxonomy-image-id'] ) && '' !== $_POST['showcase-taxonomy-image-id'] ){
          add_term_meta( $term_id, 'showcase-taxonomy-image-id', absint( $_POST['showcase-taxonomy-image-id'] ), true );
        }
        if( isset( $_POST['showcase-taxonomy-extra-detail-id'] ) && '' !== $_POST['showcase-taxonomy-extra-detail-id'] ){
          add_term_meta( $term_id, 'showcase-taxonomy-extra-detail-id',  $_POST['showcase-taxonomy-extra-detail-id'] , true );
        }
       }
  /**
    * Update the form field value
    * @since 1.0.0
    */
    function updated_category_image( $term_id, $tt_id ) {
        if( isset( $_POST['showcase-taxonomy-image-id'] ) && '' !== $_POST['showcase-taxonomy-image-id'] ){
          update_term_meta( $term_id, 'showcase-taxonomy-image-id', absint( $_POST['showcase-taxonomy-image-id'] ) );
        } else {
          update_term_meta( $term_id, 'showcase-taxonomy-image-id', '' );
        }
        if( isset( $_POST['showcase-taxonomy-extra-detail-id'] ) && '' !== $_POST['showcase-taxonomy-extra-detail-id'] ){
          update_term_meta( $term_id, 'showcase-taxonomy-extra-detail-id',  $_POST['showcase-taxonomy-extra-detail-id']  );
        } else {
          update_term_meta( $term_id, 'showcase-taxonomy-extra-detail-id', '' );
        }
      }
    /**
    * Enqueue styles and scripts
    * @since 1.0.0
    */
   function add_script() {
    if( ! isset( $_GET['taxonomy'] ) || $_GET['taxonomy'] != 'business' ) {
      return;
    } ?>
    <script> jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
      _wpMediaViewsL10n.insertIntoPost = '<?php _e( "Insert", "showcase" ); ?>';
      function ct_media_upload(button_class) {
        var _custom_media = true, _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
        $('body').on('click', button_class, function(e) {
          var button_id = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
          var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
          var button = $(button_id);
          _custom_media = true;
          wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment){
            if( _custom_media ) {
              $('#showcase-taxonomy-image-id').val(attachment.id);
              $('#category-image-wrapper').html('<img class="custom_media_image" src="" style="margin:0;padding:0;max-height:100px;float:none;" />');
              $( '#category-image-wrapper .custom_media_image' ).attr( 'src',attachment.url ).css( 'display','block' );
            } else {
              return _orig_send_attachment.apply( button_id, [props, attachment] );
            }
          }
          wp.media.editor.open(button); return false;
        });
      }
      ct_media_upload('.showcase_tax_media_button.button');
      $('body').on('click','.showcase_tax_media_remove',function(){
        $('#showcase-taxonomy-image-id').val('');
        $('#category-image-wrapper').html('<img class="custom_media_image" src="" style="margin:0;padding:0;max-height:100px;float:none;" />');
      });

      $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
        var queryStringArr = settings.data.split('&');
        if( $.inArray('action=add-tag', queryStringArr) !== -1 ){
          var xml = xhr.responseXML;
          $response = $(xml).find('term_id').text();
          if($response!=""){
            // Clear the thumb image
            $('#category-image-wrapper').html('');
          }
         }
       });
     });
   </script>
  <?php }
```